# IntelliJ does not update web resources on Wildfly8.2

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wildfly

My web resources (HTML/CSS/JS) are not updated when I use Update classes and resources in my J2EE project.  I tried almost every setting in my IntelliJ. On Frame deactivation I set Update classes and resources too - update is triggered but it just says update not needed and classes are up to date even if web resources has been changed before. Updating classes works. Actually only one way how to update HTML files is to redeploy.

To sum up my environment:

- Wildfly8.2
- IntelliJ14
- simple J2EE project
- exploded WAR artifact
- web content in ProjectName/Webcontent

Comment: This works for me hundreds of times a day, every day, without fail. You should be using maven and your content should be in src/main/webapp. If you're not using maven -- good luck you're on your own.

Comment: Also, please read [ask] because you haven't provided enough info for anyone to really help.

Comment: What role should maven play here? Static content is even updated in out/ directory, but they are just not pushed to the server. Even if I create a project with wizard and add Web application framework support, it does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was in standalone.xml in my JBoss installation. Had to rewrite

```
<jsp-config/>
```

to

```
<jsp-config development="true"/>
```

"Thanks" for vote down, but this is quite general question which can be often asked as this was default installation of wildfly.